# Who is the main character from the Love, Death and Robots episode "Tall Grass"?

Tags: love-death-and-robots

In season 2 of "Love, Death and Robots", in the episode "Tall Grass" we can see a passenger of the early twentieth century train having certain... adventures during an unplanned stop.

I don't think that his name is ever given, but he is strangely similar to HP Lovecraft (although, HPL rarely posed with glasses):

[image]

[image]

Is that just a coincidence? The last words of the train conductor seem to point to that conclusion:

> - Sir...best not to mention it to anyone. They won't believe you anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may not be the answer that you want, but the episode is based off of [Joe R. Lansdale's story of the same name](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23626097-the-tall-grass-and-other-stories). The main character is named Lairo in the short, is unnamed in the original story, and is not indicated to be anyone special.